# sqlldr escape reserved name using NULLIF

Tags: oracle, sql-loader

I have a table with a field called [SEQUENCE] and another called [REFERENCE]

I can define the field in SQLLDR as

```
SEQUENCE NULLIF ( SEQUENCE=" ")
```

It complains that SEQUENCE is A SQLLDR reserved word.

I have tried

```
"SEQUENCE"
[SEQUENCE]
\"SEQUENCE\"
```

None seem to work

Would prefer not to call SQL, because that would preclude direct path loads.

Answer (score 1):

Never Mind

Turns out you need to quote both the field name and the Nullif

```
"SEQUENCE" Nuffif("SEQUENCE"=" ")
```